# Split an XML document into sections

Tags: .net, sql-server, xml, vb.net

I know this has been asked many times but when I search I find answers from 12 years ago and I'm looking for a more current solution.  I have an XML file that looks like

```xml
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<PROJECTS xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9238972</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>R01</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC>
</row>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9238973</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>R012</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC>
</row>
<row>
<APPLICATION_ID>9238974</APPLICATION_ID>
<ACTIVITY>R013</ACTIVITY>
<ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC>
</row>
</PROJECTS>
```

And I need to save every `<row>` element to a MSSQL 2016 server as an XML element.

My current code it way too slow to do over 1 million `<row>` elements. I have text files with about 100,000 records each. My current code is:

```vb
Dim rdr As New StreamReader(ofdXML.FileName)
While (rdr.Peek >= 0)
    varLine = rdr.ReadLine
    sTag = varLine.Contains("<row>")
    eTag = varLine.Contains("</row>")
    If sTag And eTag Then
        appLine = varLine
        If appLine.Contains("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") Then
            appID = appLine.Substring(Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>"), appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") - 1)
        End If
    ElseIf sTag Then
        v1 = True
        appLine = varLine
        If appLine.Contains("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") Then
            appID = appLine.Substring(Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>"),                               appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - Len("<row><APPLICATION_ID>") - 1)
        End If
    ElseIf eTag Then
        appLine = appLine & varLine
        v1 = False
    ElseIf v1 Then
        appLine = appLine & varLine
        If appLine.Contains("<APPLICATION_ID>") Then
            Dim xi As Integer = appLine.IndexOf("_ID>") + 4
            appID = appLine.Substring(xi, appLine.IndexOf("/APPLICATION_ID") - (xi + 1))                         
        End If
    End If
```

I've tried LINQ but I can't get the syntax right for VB.NET and that might be faster.  What I would like is a more efficient way to split and save.  Currently it is taking 16 hours to do one file with 100,000 row elements.

Comment: Usually, a question contains a `?`. I'm struggling to understand what you need help with.

Comment: Read in the whole file, remove the top 2 lines, remove the bottom line, split the rest by </row>, now reattach the splitted </row> and voila, a list of 'xmls'.

Comment: The question is there a faster/ more accepted standard today to save the data.  Currently taking 16+hours for each file.

Comment: Reading and working with a 85mb file is a nightmare.  One of the reasons I was using a streamreader.  But good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

If this is a one-time import, you might consider writing a converter to read the XML file and spit out a pipe-delimted file.  Then, you could import it very easily using SQL Server's BULK INSERT command or the Import Data wizard.

Code to do the conversion would look something like...

```
    Using sw As New System.IO.StreamWriter("outputfile.txt")
        Dim xdoc As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
        xdoc.Load("InpurtFilename")
        For Each row As System.Xml.XmlNode In xdoc.SelectNodes("//xsi:row")
            Dim ApplicationId As String = row.SelectSingleNode("xsi:APPLICATION_ID").InnerText
            Dim Activity As String = row.SelectSingleNode("xsi:ACTIVITY").InnerText
            Dim AdministeringIC As String = row.SelectSingleNode("xsi:ADMINISTERING_IC").InnerText
            sw.WriteLine(String.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}", ApplicationId, Activity, AdministeringIC))
        Next
    End Using
```

Answer (score 0):

Use XML Serialization

Make classes to represent your file

```vb
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Xml.Serialization
```

```vb
<XmlRoot("PROJECTS")>
Public Class Projects
    <XmlElement("row")>
    Public Property Rows As List(Of Row)
End Class

Public Class Row
    <XmlElement("APPLICATION_ID")>
    Public Property Application_ID As Integer
    <XmlElement("ACTIVITY")>
    Public Property Activity As String
    <XmlElement("ADMINISTERING_IC")>
    Public Property Administering_IC As String
End Class
```

(I wrote some code to create a 1 million `<row>` XML file which is ~140 MB.)

```vb
Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf writeProjects)
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine($"Created file in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.")
End Sub

Private Sub writeProjects()
    Dim p As New Projects()
    p.Rows = New List(Of Row)()
    For i = 1 To 1000000
        Dim r As New Row With {
            .Application_ID = i,
            .Activity = $"R0{i}",
            .Administering_IC = "CA"
        }
        p.Rows.Add(r)
    Next
    Using writer As New StreamWriter("filename.xml")
        Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Projects))
        s.Serialize(writer, p)
    End Using
End Sub
```

> Created file in 2346 ms.

And use this code to read the file and write to your database

```vb
Private Async Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch()
    sw.Start()
    Dim p = Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf readProjects)
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine($"Read file in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.")
    sw.Restart()
    Await Task.Factory.StartNew(AddressOf writeSQL, p, TaskCreationOptions.None)
    sw.Stop()
    Console.WriteLine($"Wrote to SQL in {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms.")
End Sub

Private Function readProjects() As Projects
    Dim p As Projects
    Using reader As New StreamReader("filename.xml")
        Dim s As New XmlSerializer(GetType(Projects))
        p = DirectCast(s.Deserialize(reader), Projects)
    End Using
    Return p
End Function

Private Sub writeSQL(o As Object)
    Dim p = DirectCast(o, Projects)
    For Each r In p.Rows
        ' insert each row
        Dim q =
$"INSERT INTO [Table] (APPLICATION_ID, ACTIVITY, ADMINISTERING_IC) 
VALUES ({r.Application_ID}, '{r.Activity}', '{r.Administering_IC}')"
    Next
    ' or SQL bulk insert
End Sub
```

> Read file in 3442 ms.
>   Wrote to SQL in 625 ms.

In the line `For Each r In p.Rows` you have actual objects in memory with properties like `Application_ID`, `Activity`, and `Administering_IC`. They are inserted easily individually, which might take some time. Or you can do SQL bulk insert. Getting the objects from the file into SQL INSERT commands takes less than 5 seconds for 1 million rows.

Comment: Thanks for the code and it is extremely fast.  I'm playing with this and was wondering how to pass in the entire XML row element.  I would like to pass in only the APPLICATION_ID and the Row XML element.  I have a procedure in the SQL that will read the XML and parse it.  I want to time the difference between passing in individual elements verse the entire row XML   Is there a way to add that in the Row class?  My sample XML above only has 3 elements my real code has 45.  I tested your code with a file that has 325 records and it took 1.48 seconds for one field

Comment: As I added 16 additional fields my time went up to 32 seconds for the same 325 records

Comment: my ADO time keeps creeping up on each save

Comment: @user1314159 Perhaps you could use a table-valued parameter to send the data in batches of perhaps 1000 rows, and use a stored procedure to insert that data. Everything you'd need to know about that: [Using Table-Valued Parameters in SQL Server and .NET](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2008.html).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [XElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement):

```vb
Dim xml = XElement.Load("PATH_TO_FILE")
Dim rows = xml.<row>
For Each row In rows
    Dim app_id = row.<APPLICATION_ID>.First.Value
    Dim activity = row.<ACTIVITY>.First.Value
    Dim adm_ic = row.<ADMINISTERING_IC>.First.Value
    WriteLine($"app_id: {app_id} activity {activity}, adm_ic: {adm_ic}")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method how to split an XML file into fragments and `INSERT` each XML fragment into a DB table via `BULK Load` on the SQL Server side. You can package that SQL into a stored procedure and call it from the VB.NET side.

> SQL

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE (ID INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY, APPLICATION_ID INT, xml_fragment XML);

;WITH XmlFile (xmlData) AS
(
    SELECT TRY_CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) 
    FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'e:\Temp\Split XML file into fragments.xml', SINGLE_BLOB) AS x
)
, rs AS
(
    SELECT c.value('(APPLICATION_ID/text())[1]','INT') AS [APPLICATION_ID]
        , c.query('.') AS [xml_fragment]
    FROM XmlFile CROSS APPLY xmlData.nodes('(/PROJECTS/row)') AS t(c)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl (APPLICATION_ID, xml_fragment)
SELECT * FROM rs;

-- test
SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

> Output

```
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ID | APPLICATION_ID |                                                    xml_fragment                                                     |
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 |        9238972 | <row><APPLICATION_ID>9238972</APPLICATION_ID><ACTIVITY>R01</ACTIVITY><ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC></row>  |
|  2 |        9238973 | <row><APPLICATION_ID>9238973</APPLICATION_ID><ACTIVITY>R012</ACTIVITY><ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC></row> |
|  3 |        9238974 | <row><APPLICATION_ID>9238974</APPLICATION_ID><ACTIVITY>R013</ACTIVITY><ADMINISTERING_IC>CA</ADMINISTERING_IC></row> |
+----+----------------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: I tried this and after 5 or so hours trying to load this from any other drive other than C: on the server it would not work. E or D would not work.  I know it must be a permission thing  I kept getting a file not found.   Is there a way that I can pass this into a Stored Procedure?  I have a process that will parses the XML and store each item into it's own field. Also is there a way to save it as two Columns?  One with the APPLICATION_ID and one with the xml_fragment?  That way if I store each record I can run a process on the records that have not be parsed

Comment: I got it to save APPLICATION_ID as a separate field

Comment: Trying again and going part 7 hours

Comment: (1) I adjusted the answer to accommodate APPLICATION_ID as a separate  column. (2) Fully qualified path on the file system to the XML file shall be visible to the SQL Server instance. You may need to copy the XML file to the server where SQL Server is installed.